# How to send message to feed dialog using facebook sdk in android

Tags: android, facebook, dialog, facebook-android-sdk

i am creating an app for share something to facebook. here when i click on a button the feed dialog box will come for sharing, there is a text box for adding message, my need is that i need to send a data to the text box from my code. how can i send it ??

and this is my code to show the feed dialog box.

```
private void showFeedDialog() {
        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("description","message from me ");
        postParams.putString("link", "https://www.google.com");
        WebDialog feedDialog = new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this, Session.getActiveSession(),postParams)
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                if(error==null)
                {
                    final String postId=values.getString("post_id");
                    if(postId!=null)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Posted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Post canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                    if(error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Publish canceled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).build();
        feedDialog.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify a user message to the feed dialog. The "name", "caption", and "description" fields only apply to the "link" that's being shared.

This is by design.

Comment: is there any way to update user message in feed dialog?

Comment: No, that would be "prefilling the message", which is against FB's platform policies.

Comment: which parameter for Facebook friend's wall on text-field on passing string for app?

Answer (score 0):

The code for Publishing your Feed using the new Facebook SDK 3.0 is as follows:

```
// Method for publishing a feed to Facebook
private void publishStory() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
    postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK 3.0 Test By Arshad");
    postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
    postParams.putString("description",
                    "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
    postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
    postParams.putString("picture",
                    "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

    Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCompleted FacebookRequest Done");
            JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject()
                    .getInnerJSONObject();
            try {
                graphResponse.getString("id");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
            }
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "FacebookRequestError" + error.getErrorMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "FacebookRequest Done");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Story Published to Your Wall", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };

    Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams,
            HttpMethod.POST, callback);

    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
    task.execute();
}
```

Comment: You can pass your message in any of the three fields : name, caption or description.

Comment: yaa i pass it as you said.. but it doesn't appear in the text box that  provided in the feed dialog box.. its appear below the text box

Comment: try using the method which I have pasted above and then reply

Comment: yaa am already done using this method.... i got every thing.. on my feed dialog but they are not editable.. i need the message on the edittext box on the feed dialog which i send from my code..

Comment: you can just design a layout and make an edittext box in which the user enters the message. Then when the user clicks on the share button you can pass the message in the edittext to the may be name field. postParams.putString("name", edittext.getText().toString());

Comment: am getting null point exception from this line `JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject()
                    .getInnerJSONObject();`

Comment: You first need to get publishing permissions from the user.

Answer (score 0):

To post message from activity use this

```
    Bundle postParams = new Bundle(); 
    postParams.putString("message", "your message");
    postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK 3.0 Test By Arshad");
    postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
    postParams.putString("description",
                    "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
    postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
    postParams.putString("picture",
                    "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");
```