# Post to Facebook wall without using ShareDialog in Facebook 4.+

Tags: android

I am working on an app that I want to be able to post to Facebook wall. The language used for the app is non-latin based character set. Hence, the user types the content to share using the app itself and then share it on facebook without going to the ShareDialog as the content is already typed. I am using Facebook SDK for Android 4.+. Can anyone help me on doing this? All example I got is posting using ShareDialog. Facebook SDK seems to have classes like ShareLinkContent, SharePhoto, ShareMedia but no class to attach simple text content which I am trying to do. Or, can I make the content already typed appear on the ShareDialog's EditText?

Comment: I think you always need to write text with feed dialog as i know `Facebook` is not allowing to static text to post always. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265731/how-to-send-message-to-feed-dialog-using-facebook-sdk-in-android

Comment: But that is bad behavior because I should be able to type the text anywhere and then just post it. In my case, it is not possible to type the message on ShareDialog's EditText since it is non-latin based.

Comment: Why is the language an issue? Surely a user can type in non-latin characters in Facebook's ShareDialog?

Comment: Because I want to do spell check and stuff like that before posting. Also I don't want users to install new Soft Input keyboard for typing but do it easily without installing.

Comment: Thank you all for replying. I am considering to use SocialAuth Android SDK instead of Facebook SDK based on your response. SocialAuth looks more appropriate considering users should be able to post to both Facebook and Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does not allow you to pre-fill the ShareDialog's text. As far as I know there also is no other way to post content on a user's wall.

What is possible is share a link using the ShareDialog, and you can pre-fill the link description and other attributes like image and title but I guess that's not what you want.

An example of that is:

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
.setContentDescription(descriptionString)
.setContentUrl(Uri.parse(urlString))
.setImageUrl(Uri.parse(pictureUrlString))
.setContentTitle(titleString)
.build();
ShareDialog dialog = new ShareDialog(this);
dialog.show(content);
```

Comment: Does that mean the message should always be typed in ShareDialog's EditText? Can't I post the message in my app to facebook?

Comment: I don't think that's possible no

Comment: Quite odd behavior. In SDK versions prior to 4.0, I think it is possible. They removed it in SDK 4.0?!

Comment: @birraa I'm not 100% sure but I think it was indeed possible in older versions but that was way back in version 2.x I believe. I think it's not possible since version 3.x but I could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void showFacebookShareDialog() {

    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentDescription(
                        "Share Text")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                .build();

        shareDialog.show(linkContent);

    }
}
```

Comment: I want to post simple text content to the wall just like it is typed into the SharedDialog itself, not link. Thanks for replying.

Comment: post Simple text is not possible